# Can I change grub2 default OS from LiveCD

Tags: boot, grub2, live-cd

I can't find anywhere on the internet that has this specific question.

The problem for me is I forgot my pass for Ubuntu 13.04 and now I can't use sudo commands. So now I need to change the boot and I cant do it. I want to make the default boot Windows on grub2.

Any ideas?  If worse comes to worse can i delete the ubuntu partitions from windows then repair the grub so it will only show the windows os.

Ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

if I'm correctly understanding, you've forgot your own password in Ubuntu (I suppose you set up automatic login) so you can't run commanda as superuser: am I right?

In this case, what about starting Ubuntu in single-user mode and change your password? (take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password))

Cheers,

Silvia